# Primefaces datatable formatação de números

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Como eu posso formatar uma coluna (CEP) do datatable com a máscara "*00.000-000*"?

**Exemplo:**

**Valor:** *90560120* - **Saída:** *90.560-120*

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: `<f:convertNumber pattern="00.000.000"/>`, mas não achei uma forma de colocar o hífen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer um `input` então a resposta do @Anderson é mais adequada. Caso queira apenas um `OutputText` ou `OutputLabel` eu recomendo criar seu próprio converter, teria uma semântica melhor, um entendimento mais claro do que está sendo feito e é facilmente reutilizado em outras telas.

O seu facelets ficaria:

```
<h:outputText value="#{seuBean.cep}">
    <f:converter converterId="CEPConverter" />
</h:outputText>
```

E o converter ficaria:

```
@FacesConverter("CEPConverter")
public class CEPConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        String[] parts = value.split("-\\.");
        return Integer.parseInt(join(parts));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        String valueAsString = value.toString();
        return formatCEP(valueAsString.substring(0, 2), valueAsString.substring(2, 5), valueAsString.substring(5));
    }

    private String formatCEP(String part1, String part2, String part3) {
        return part1.concat(".").concat(part2).concat("-").concat(part3);
    }

    private String join(String[] parts) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String part : parts) {
            sb.append(part);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Essa é uma implementação bem simples, você pode até melhorar/customiza-lá conforme seu entendimento.

Comment: Usando `Converter` como eu poderia passar a máscara como parâmetro?

Comment: Você teria que criar uma **tag**, registrando esse Converter. Posso incluir um exemplo daqui a pouco em minha resposta. Mas a princípio, a resposta do [**lefloh**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905680/3404639) e do [**chuckedw**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29398138/3404639) nessa [**pergunta**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613134/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-with-arguments) abordam esse assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Ainda estou procurando uma forma mais siples, mas acabei solucionando desta forma:

*dataTable*:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.format('##.###-###', item.cep, true)}" style="float:left"/>
```

*Bean*:

```
public String format(String pattern, Object value, boolean suppressZero) {
    if (!suppressZero || Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) != 0) {
        MaskFormatter mask;
        try {
            mask = new MaskFormatter(pattern);
            mask.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
            return mask.valueToString(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que criar um converter que salva apenas os números seja a forma mais simples de resolver esta questão.

```
package br.com.t2tecnologia;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("app.numbersConverter")
public class AppNumbersConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return value.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "");
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

}
```

No .xhtml:

```
<p:inputMask mask="99.999-999" id="enderecoCepText" value="#{e.cep}" size="10"
             converter="app.numbersConverter"
             required="true" requiredMessage="CEP não informado."/>
```

Uso este converter para vários outros dados, como CPF, CNPJ, etc, para armazenar apenas os números na coluna do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

O mais indicado pra usar no seu caso seria o componente inputMask do Primefaces.
No seu caso a tag ficaria assim: `<p:inputMask mask="99.999-9999"/>`

Você pode encontrar mais falando da tag [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml).

Comment: O `p:inputMask` não funcionou, pois estou apenas listando os dados, não editando. Link quebrado!